# PHP converting nbsp to " "

Tags: php, html, scripting

I have been trying to get this to work for the last 3 hours but to no avail.

```
<?php
    foreach ($array as $item) {
      $item = preg_replace("~ (?=[^<>]*(<|$))~", "&nbsp;", $item);
      logWrite($item);
      echo $item;
    }
?>
```

the `$array` is made up of a list of items e.g. `"bread"`, `"cheese"`, `"red wine"` - the regexp is there to make sure it only works on text between the open and close html tags (courtesy of someone else here).

Anyway the problem is that when I write to the log - it comes out as `"bread"`, `"cheese"`, `"red&nbsp;wine"` but the echo (I have tried print as well) on the html page is unchanged from `"bread"`, `"cheese"`, `"red wine"`.

If I use a different character to replace e.g. `&reg;` it works fine. Any ideas why this particular entity does not work? I think my charsets are all fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you viewing the source of the web page or rendering the page with a browser? Keep in mind that `"red&nbsp;wine"` in the source will be displayed as `"red wine"` by a browser.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use regexp here. Try with:

```
$item = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $item);
```

If you want to check if `&nbsp;` is between HTML tags, you should do it before (`if` statement, etc) - it will be more clear.

However do not use regexp with html - it's evil.

Comment: Hmm thanks I started off using str_replace and moved to the regexp as one of the items is an email address mailto.. why is regexp evil with html?

Comment: @jamo_ Spend a while on this article. It's worth: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Thanks. `htmlspecialchars()` fixed my issue but if the regexp is bad practice I will have a look through that. cheers!

Comment: It definitely is ;-) Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp;` is an HTML entity for "non-breaking space", so it's going to appear as a space (not the actual characters) in an HTML document, therefore you will not notice the difference between `&nbsp;` and a normal space. View the source code and you will see it.

Comment: Oh ok, you had said "on the html page", and said the `&reg;` "worked" so I assumed you were viewing HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're interested in decoding all HTML entities, you can use `html_entity_decode`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

It's much simpler than trying to use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to display "raw" HTML content on a HTML page, you should use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
echo htmlspecialchars( $item );
```

Comment: Ah brilliant that was it!! thanks :-) I had even used that on another page - can't believe I forgot about it!

Answer (score 0):

As per http://magp.ie/2011/01/06/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string-with-php/

> I had some character that the parser does not know how to interput because it was outside the byte range of the UTF8 format. Some of the PHP functions, like iconv, still let some non-UTF8 characters through which breaks the parser. The preg_replace just rips out any non-UTF8 character based on it’s byte sequence and replaces it with a question mark.

```
//reject overly long 2 byte sequences, as well as characters above U+10000 and replace with ?
$some_string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x10\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x19\x7F]'.
 '|[\x00-\x7F][\x80-\xBF]+'.
 '|([\xC0\xC1]|[\xF0-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF]*'.
 '|[\xC2-\xDF]((?![\x80-\xBF])|[\x80-\xBF]{2,})'.
 '|[\xE0-\xEF](([\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]))|(?![\x80-\xBF]{2})|[\x80-\xBF]{3,})/S',
 '?', $some_string );

//reject overly long 3 byte sequences and UTF-16 surrogates and replace with ?
$some_string = preg_replace('/\xE0[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]'.
 '|\xED[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]/S','?', $some_string );
```